# Use WSO2 ESB to add CORS header to WSO2 DSS service

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to access the DSS service from my web application, it is cross domain. So I figured the ESB can help with the property mediator to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. But I am having no luck adding the appropriate headers.

What are the steps to implement this correctly?

Update:

Solved it. For those trying to resolve this, I had to add the headers at pre-flight to get to the resources, i.e. at OPTIONS.

Comment: Having no luck doing what?  You're more likely to get help if you tell us what you've tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: I see you've tried to add the answer via an update to your question. You should post that update as an answer below.